# Why does my text get cut out as soon as it hits multiple lines?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, android-wrap-content

I have a simple `RecyclerView` using 2 strings. As soon as the 2nd `TextView` gets multiple lines of text, it gets cut out instead of just expanding the height of the view.

[image]

For example the text that two textViews received was:

```
"Director":"Cate Shortland"
"Writer":"Jac Schaeffer (story by), Ned Benson (story by), Eric Pearson (screenplay by), Stan Lee (based on the Marvel comics by), Don Heck (based on the Marvel comics by), Don Rico (based on the Marvel comics by)"
```

My view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/detial"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/detial" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:text="@string/year"
        android:maxLines="24"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried changing from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`, adding `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` and checked that the `RecyclerView` is the latest version (because of some bug that earlier versions had). Any ideas what I could try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:maxWidth="250dp"
    android:text="@string/year"
    android:maxLines="24"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraint"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/detial" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this should do the trick , basically  android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraint" is the most inmportant param here in this case

Comment: I am sorry but my android knowledge isn't really high. Im not sure what should i write into dimen/match_constraint.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that :D     <dimen name="match_constraint">0dp</dimen>

Answer (score 0):

Change your textview width as **match_parent**.

Its working fine with your text content

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:maxWidth="250dp"
    android:text="Jac Schaeffer (story by), Ned Benson (story by), Eric Pearson (screenplay by), Stan Lee (based on the Marvel comics by), Don Heck (based on the Marvel comics by), Don Rico (based on the Marvel comics by)"
    android:maxLines="24"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I tried that too though what happens is that i writes over the first textView.

Comment: you should set constraint correctly and set width as match parent